# How should we go about users "rage quitting" Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Today I came [across a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29737737/4418587) that seemed a little too broad and I asked him to elaborate.

Then, the user began ranting and says he "quits the site" and some other harsh words.

How should I handle this situation from here?

Posts like these certainly lower the quality of the site and  should most likely be removed.

But, should I bring it to the attention of a moderator or try and handle it myself?

Comment: I hate to say this, but users who react unconstructively like that are probably not the kind of users that we want. So I think the answer is: Let them quit. It's better for us, it's better for them.

Comment: I wouldn't call this rage quitting. Rage quitting is normally when a user defaces their posts, unaccepts previous answers they had accepted, etc. This is more like quitter whining.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 Then how should we act with the questions he already wrote? It leaves a bad impression on new users and the community as a whole.

Comment: Firstly, flag the question as other for moderator attention, explain that the user is leaving unconstructive comments on this question. Secondly, just downvote/flag to close/do nothing as you see fit for the question you run into naturally. Don't necessarily scope out his other stuff *to get back at him*. I don't think any comment replying back to him would help right now. So just ignore after flag for mod attention.

Comment: In cases like this where the question already has downvotes, it's probably best to just do nothing. Negatively voted questions with no answers get auto-deleted after a while. Flagging comments consumes moderator time so I'd save that for something more serious such as personal attacks and insults.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 Ragequitting simply refers to leaving an online venue in a (usually passive-aggressive) huff. All the other stuff you mentioned can certainly accompany ragequitting sometimes, but are not a necessary condition for it.

Comment: Where can I see the actual rage?  It's not visible in the screenshot. I feel cheated because I came to enjoy some good raging...

Comment: Well, moderators are harsh and you get the blocking warning very soon. I think when someone asks a question, he should be encourages, but here people especially moderators discourages people by restrictions, closing questions and using warning like statements. Be polite to others and there is no need to be an ass-hole when it comes to moderating. I hate them too.

Comment: @vicky - Um, the only moderator here was me, and I came by only after all this had taken place to clean it up. How is it "too harsh" to politely request clarification of a question? How does that deserve being insulted by the person asking a question? Also, the "ban warning" you mention is there to give you advance warning that you might run into problems, and is provided to try to help you understand when you've been asking poorly-received questions. It's helped a lot of people improve their questions.

Comment: that seems like a pretty specific question to me.

Comment: I don't know about this particular case, but I know of some very smart and productive users who have quit SO because of its silly rules. These were the opposite of "probably not the kind of users that we want." Speak for yourself.

Comment: @lwburk If they don't like the communities rules, then they probably don't belong in it? I don't understand what is wrong about an opinion.

Comment: That's odd on the screen shot you scribble out the user name and profile, but you link directly to the post.  So much for animosity.

Comment: It wasn't my screenshot, the original comments were quickly deleted so I didn't add one, someone else felt as it was needed and edited it in there.

Comment: @JonH Only >10k users can see the link, so it's anonymous to not-logged-in users and riff-raff like me :)

Comment: I'm not sure "Sounds like the only egocentric person is you man by the way" was particularly constructive though..

Comment: I like comments where people tell the questioner, "please post your code", or other very specific suggestions about how to correct what is lacking.  (Disclaimer: I have no idea how Echohonest works.) In looking at his question, I felt he actually gave all the information needed: he posted a URL which according to his understanding of the docs should have returned results, but didn't.  That seems like all the info needed to frame the question.   So either giving a specific suggestion for clarification or leaving a post alone (when you don't know the technology) may be the best policy.

Comment: Let them go to Yahoo Answers

Comment: I thought rage-quitting was hitting Alt+F4 when you die and lose all your diamond gear in a pool of magma.  I don't understand how this idea carries-over to web forums.  I think "trolling" is sufficient or "the last trolling of a troll" if you want to get wordy about it.  As such, the normal rules for trolls would apply here.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you see comments devolving into rants (as they were here), flag them and we'll clean them up. Those comments didn't really add anything to the site, and were somewhat insulting of those asking him for clarification, so I removed them on seeing the flags here.

In addition, it was not clear what issue they were having, and they stated that they had resolved it and wouldn't be clarifying this further, so I figured this question could be deleted without loss.

They are free to follow the instructions we provide for how to delete their account, if they wish to leave. I don't know that there's much we can do to convince them to stay if a few downvotes and a constructive comment cause them to flip out like this.

Answer (score 27):

The more people who post such questions and react in the similar manner quit, the better it will be for a community. You tried to help, you help was not appreciated. Forget and move on.

Answer (score 20):

Unless the user starts posting offensive or inflammatory messages, let 'em go [and cool off].  There's nothing that can really be done by a moderator to make them stick around, so flagging the post isn't going to accomplish much.

If they do start posting a ton of offensive or inflammatory messages, then you can flag with a custom flag to get a mod's attention.

Comment: If they start posting offensive messages, there's plenty the moderators can and should do. A temporary ban seems appropriate. If that makes them quit the site, good riddance.

Comment: @Lundin:  I hope that I didn't say anything to the contrary, as that's exactly where a moderator can step in.

Comment: @Lundin: Hmm... I can't help but feel there can be a risk of constructive moderation, e.g. passive aggressive "asking for clarification" and "suggesting improvements to questions" mostly intended at getting a rise out of people. Perhaps I've spent too much time on reddit. Of course people are apt to decide to feel victimised themselves, though the phrasing of comments can make a lot of difference.

Answer (score 6):

The goal should always be useful content that becomes an asset to others.

All parties should remember this. You're getting your question answered as a by-product of this goal, not because someone owes it to you. When you answer a question, the goal is broader than to help one stuck questioner.

The same applies to moderators. Too much emphasis on the rules can result in good content being lost. A light touch when moderating, downvoting and flagging is plenty to ensure that marginal or junk content sinks into obscurity.

Answer (score -16):

We all are looking for the answers here! Instead of it, we're finding the community that may help us make a question, or a comment that fits in the rules.
This makes people to rage quit. They will come back with other question, and will rage quit again, I guess.

Comment: You are building the COMMUNITY, that is useless in looking for the answers, but is good in looking for another community-compatible people.

Comment: Tough crowd hey?

Comment: No, Regular) Don't worry. I am dislike resistant.

Comment: Why? Downvote if you feel like you need to!)

Comment: This little microcosm is pretty much the reason why I rarely participate in meta. Make a valid but controversial statement and suddenly you get mass-downvoted. I guess that's how it's "supposed" to work but it does make for an interesting idea of a community.

Comment: @patrickvacek What you describe is a good thing. Meta is all about figuring out what the best course of action is when the FAQ/rules don't help, and we do that by voting. This answer is apparently not the solution most of the community is looking for in this specific scenario, so now we know that for when this situation arises again in the future. The accepted answer has tons of votes, so that means that the community thinks that is the best solution. Democracy at it's finest.

Comment: @patrickvacek Meta votes are not to separate "good" from "bad". That's annoying but that's how meta works.

Comment: I have explained the way I see the situation about rage quit, And the reason of Rage Quit for most people -- is YOU. Sure it hurts. 50 mins gave me -9 DownVotes, And let me get the max of it! I'm ready. And I was ready for this when I posted the answer.

Comment: This is an interesting interpretation of "democracy". I'm not even strictly opposed to it, it's just fascinating. Meta's Help says, "For most posts, votes reflect the perceived usefulness." So valid criticism or descent is not useful? I just don't like the idea of a community that smothers internal critique. And yes, I know, the post hasn't been deleted, but by downvoting and reducing Tony's score to a pittance, you are essentially discouraging disagreement and reinforcing conformity to predefined standards. That seems unproductive.

Comment: Oops, I misspelled "dissent" as "descent", and I forgot that votes don't affect score on SO meta. Still.

Comment: @patrickvacek - I hear you, its "Animal Farm". You are allowed to ask any question, but as long as you ask it like we want.

Comment: @TonyShor, what you say sounds accurate, but do you think it's a bad thing?  Certainly we are all looking for answers, but questions like "write this code for me" or "it doesn't work" don't help anybody.  Criticism can be difficult to receive sometimes, but as long as it's constructive it can be more useful than simply giving an answer.

Comment: @Brian, There are totally useless answers/questions from people that are too lazy to simply google what they need. Undeniable truth! But this community appears to be targeted to erase all of the imperfect questns/answrs, even if they are good and valuable. If there's something wrong with qstn/nswr -- you will see a hundred advices how to make it better, but you will see, perhaps, one advice, how to find the way to the solution you are looking for. I have two questions! And it's the second time I have to answer it on my own.

Comment: @Brian, What's the point in StckOvrflw and this Oversmart in creating questions community then?

Comment: @patrickvacek As the downvote tooltip says, "this post is not useful". It's not an answer to OPs question; it's just a (heavily opinionated) assesment of the situation, which does not further the debate in any way. In its current form, it would hardly be worth being a comment. Thus of course it should be downvoted. And re the statement made; it's no coincidence that it's usually made by fairly new users, often struggling to clearly express themselves in english, or unaware of SOs goals and rules. Far more people have absolutely no problem asking and answering on SO, which already disproves it.

Comment: @l4mpi, Question is:"What to do?" and the Best Answer is:"Let them Leave. Mark as "bad" and "see ya" to them. Nuff said!" but my Answer is:"Community Makes People Rage Quit." If you can understand things like this, you see that I mean "Stop being what you are and become a Human for some time, cause that people needed help and found only criticism of Mind Giants like You!" Am I expressing myself good enough for you?

Comment: You're just repeating the same crap that has been stated thousands of times by people who don't understand SO. This is not a personal help site, it's a community-built knowledge repository. If somebody badly edits a wikipedia page and their edits are rolled back and that makes them ragequit, that is not a problem with the wikipedia community but with the offending user. The same principle applies here - if somebody fails to adhere to the SO quality standards, the correct response is not to ignore those standards in fear that they will leave the site.

Comment: omg. I'm asking a question, I want to see the answer. You call it "knowledge repository" and not "a personal help". Wikipedia is way more different from SO, okay? There are two things common -- the Information and rules to share it. I'm okay with this! Rules! Great! But let's not talk about Rules for a little while. Let's talk about Information. Okay?

Comment: All the Information it gives to the regular user are: "Don't write bad about our Communty! Don't write Bad... and actually, Don't write at all!" Guess it's time for me to Rage Quit. I'm definitely tired.

Comment: @TonyShor when you see dozens of "why isn't my jquery code working" when the script isn't even loaded questions everyday, you'll understand.

Comment: Nice one mate! Sorry I up voted your answer

Comment: "Wikipedia is way more different from SO, okay?" Only because people misuse it. In concept, Stack Overflow is probably *the most Wikipedia-like* place on the Internet for questions about writing code.

Comment: Putting aside the actual opinion expressed, this is an off-topic rant about why people don't like Stack Overflow. It does not address the *topic at hand*, which is *how to respond to individuals* who end up disliking Stack Overflow. Voted to delete.