# How to avoid editing war

Tags: discussion, edits

I have been answering questions about fairly specific technical topics and libraries - mostly ones for which I am a lead developer -- for several years.   Over the past few days, one person (who I do not know and who does not regularly discuss the topics or tools) has edited several of my answers.  All the answers that have been edited in this way were asked and answered more than two years ago, and that answer was accepted more than two years ago.  Several answers have a few upvotes.  In many of these cases, my answer is the only answer to the question.

I would like the original answers reverted. For a few of these, I did restore the original answer but it was re-edited by a moderator. I have asked nicely to please revert the original answers in comments to the question, but it has not happened.

Is there a place to report such abuse? I have a specific editor and moderator to report.

I do not know if there is an official policy on editing accepted answers, but I will say this:  Answering technical questions on SO is entirely my choice. I am under no obligation to participate in this forum at all.  For the topic I focus on, there are very few people answering questions.

Why would anyone expect a volunteer subject-matter expert to keep answering questions on this forum when it is tolerated that someone with no knowledge of the subject is allowed to edit accepted answers?

I am baffled and demotivated by this process. When the answers are reverted, I may answer questions on SO again. Until that happens, I will not.   If the original answers are not reverted, I will delete them.

Comment: If you're referring to edits like the one that removed an "aside" addressed to a particular user, in relation to that user's pattern of asking instead of to one specific question, then it's standard practice for other users to edit out this kind of content. Not because it didn't have value (it looked like the kind of thing that would have been helpful to the question asker), but because it doesn't have *general* applicability - answers on SO are valued *even more* for their usefulness to *future* viewers than they are for helping the original asker.

Comment: The removed content looks like it would have been a great comment (although maybe not worked with the comment character limits) but the consensus is that it shouldn't be part of an answer. Although your answering or not is your choice, it would be too bad if valuable answers like the ones you've already provided got deleted, especially since the upvotes show people have found it helpful.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Saying "The consensus is that it shouldn't be part of an answer" implies that there was a discussion about what should be part of the answer.  There was no such discussion.  There were no comments like "Hey, you might move this part to a comment".  The content was simply deleted without discussion.  I asked to have it reverted.  And I strongly disagree with the idea that the removed content was not general or relevant: it most certainly was. both.  You all are on the verge of losing a contributor.  One more time: please revert these answers.

Comment: It is a site wide consensus, so it has previously been discussed and locked in stone.  It will not be discussed on the comments for your answer because it has already been decided.

Comment: Just to be clear - StackOverflow is not a discussion site.  If your answer contains any kind of chit chat, then it will be removed (if someone actually 
 spots it - there are a lot of questions to check).  The person who did the editing was correct.  You have failed to understand the nature of this site.

Comment: @JK  Um, "chit chat"?  Er, no.  But, OK, it is clear to me that I will not be answering any more questions on this site.  I'll delete the edited answers and log out.

Comment: Ok since you didn't link the answer in question, let's take a look. You said in your answer `I apologize to all reading this for answering here a little outside the norms of StackOverflow.  This is more like a long comment than an answer ... ` etc.  That is 100% chit chat and was quite correctly removed.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/68628445/325727

Comment: After the answer was edited, you replaced the entire text with `this answer was removed by the author `.  That is also 100% not allowed, you gave up the right to remove the content when you posted it - check the site rules.  This change of yours was also correctly removed.

Comment: @MNewville - So because you were told that removing meta commentary out of an answer is absolutely a valid exit proposal your solution was to vandalize your answer? You might read the license you agreed to when you submitted your answer, the answer doesn’t belong to you, it belongs to the community, while I don’t see value in that particular answer you vandalized you still can’t vandalize it just because you want to. The question also isn’t eligible to be deleted since it’s accepted

Comment: @JK, yes, I did not realize that I could not edit or remove accepted answers that t I provided.  I mistakenly assumed that I had a voice in any discussion of answers that I wrote and which show my name as having answered.   There is a "delete" option shown, though it seems this is not allowed for accepted answers.  This is all completely new to me: I've been answering questions for years and never experienced this before.  But the responses are consistent and clearly show a difference in priorities and values.

Comment: "Is there a place to report such abuse?" To be clear, is it your opinion that such edits are *inherently* abusive *because* they are made to old answers? Or else what exactly is the basis for your grievance?

Comment: "I mistakenly assumed that I had a voice in any discussion of answers that I wrote and which show my name as having answered." You absolutely do. However, having a voice in things has absolutely nothing to do with whether you are correct about established policy.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel my grievance is that the content of old, accepted answers (and not "chit chat" as JK described it with a cherry-picked example) was removed without discussion or suggestion to improve the answer.  That's not editing, that's changing. Certainly "Why bother with altering historical answers" is part of my complaint,  but the parts that were removed were not all fluff.   Saying "Hey how about replacing this fluffy bit with something more general, more succinct, etc" would be a fine conversation to have (and akin to the editing of a scientific journal). That is not what happened.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "I mistakenly assumed that I had a voice in any discussion of answers that I wrote and which show my name as having answered." You absolutely do."  Er, it appears to me that I do not.  All the attempts I have made over the past few days to edit my own answers were immediately reverted, without any discussion.  I am baffled by the discussion here and feel the exact opposite of "encouraged and motivated to answer questions on Stackoverflow".

Comment: @MNewville - The edit removed meta commentary indicating the answer was actually commentary. So you could argue that the only correct action is to delete your commentary submitted as an answer. The community shouldn’t have to ask you to improve the answer, it probably shouldn’t have been submitted, since you indicated when you submitted the answer it was just commentary. In the end someone saw potential and removed the meta commentary from your answer. You have any examples of other edits being reversed other then the one edit that was appropriate?

Comment: So I found this justifiable [edit proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49363237/2) to an answer that also likely was just commentary. Majority of the rollbacks also included a moderator, the edits to your answers, are appropriate and you roll back those appropriate edits is not justified.

Comment: It is new to you that you're not allowed to vandalize your own posts, although you're a member for 8 years? Really? It looks more like you're a little bit angry someone dared to edit your posts and now you want to rage-quit, but failed to do so, so you came to meta to complain.

Comment: @user16217248 the content removed was not fluff-like greetings.  It did include guidance on how to ask better questions which also gives context to why an answer might be "general" or incomplete, and so should NOT be removed without discussion.  If it had been suggested at the time of answering to move this to comments,  I would have happily done so.  That was not suggested.  They were not "edit proposals", there was no discussion at all.  The content was simply removed without discussion.  Attempts to restore the original content were all rejected.   OK, you win (or maybe not?).

Comment: I find your ultimatum disturbing, but appropriate edits won’t be rolled back, so it’s also an empty threat. Guidance on asking better questions DO NOT BELONG in the body of an answer. Your rollback proposal edits were rejected by both community user(s) and community moderator(s).

Comment: Cherry picking eh? No I just need to show one example to prove the point.  But since you need more, how about this one `I support @mikuszefski's answer`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66846932/325727.  Or how about the one found by Security Hound above?  Looks like there  are plenty of examples to be found in your answers.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I have never had any of this sort of thing happen before.  But you have the timing backwards.  It was suggested to post to meta first, so I did.  For me, the answer shows that I can delete it, but that fails to work for accepted posts.  It's not so much "rage quitting" as that in academic circles, what you write is who you are, and if someone is changing my answer, it really isn't my answer anymore, and that appeared to be the only possible way to delete the answer.  Anyway, yes, it is sort of odd that an author cannot delete or retract an answer.

Comment: It has always been this way.  Any text that does not answer the question can be deleted immediately and without warning.  It can be any text, it is not limited to only greetings and thanks. And the editor will be correct in doing so.  Saying `I support @mikuszefski's answer` does not answer the question.   If you have not learnt this after eight years then this is entirely on you - this policy is much more than 8 years old.

Comment: @JK ... just completely baffled that "yes, I agree with the answer from X, and building on that..." is viewed as something that should be removed.  I am definitely in the wrong place.

Comment: Here's another one. They are not hard to find in your answers.  `It is always helpful to post a complete, minimal example of what you are trying to do. Without a complete example, only vague answers are possible.` https://stackoverflow.com/a/65364500/325727.  It does not answer the question so do not include it in the answer.  It's not a hard concept to understand.  No cherry picking here.  BTW if the question is vague and hard to understand, then do not answer.  This is not GuessOverflow.

Comment: If you need to expand on the importance of minimal reproducible examples in an answer, you're answering the wrong questions. Questions that lack these should simply be closed.

Comment: And - no one is targeting you in particular with these edits even though you seem to think this is some vast conspiracy against you.  I just noticed that another person's answer on the same question you answered says `Am I wrong or are you making your life too complicated.`. - thats chit chat and I will edit it out right now. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66779850/325727

Comment: @MNewville - “Anyway, yes, it is sort of odd that an author cannot delete or retract an answer.” - An answer author can delete an answer if its hasn’t been accepted. If you had contacted SO staff to eliminate the answer from your profile, that can be done but that typically done, as an exception not because you disagree with an edit proposal by a community moderator. You not being aware of the rules and accepted behavior, is not an excuse, for you vandalize your own answers. I also don’t believe you didn’t know some of these revelations after 8 years and hundreds of upvotes

Comment: "but the parts that were removed were not all fluff" - someone making a legitimate complaint here would be expected to demonstrate this with concrete examples. "They were not "edit proposals", there was no discussion at all." There are processes whereby edit proposals are considered. They do not necessarily involve the author, but they are reviewed. "Saying "Hey how about replacing this fluffy bit with something more general, more succinct, etc" would be a fine conversation to have" - no, it would not, any more than "hey, maybe the sky is not actually yellow" would be.

Comment: "in academic circles, what you write is who you are, and if someone is changing my answer, it really isn't my answer anymore" - I can just picture it now: `I apologize to all reading this for answering here a little outside the norms of the university. This is more like a long comment than a thesis statement...` "just completely baffled that "yes, I agree with the answer from X, and building on that..." is viewed as something that should be removed." - imagine if you were reading an article on Wikipedia, and you saw that phrase in the middle suddenly out of nowhere.

Comment: Such commentary would probably be removed from even a Wikipedia article, so we definitely, don’t want it in answers to our own questions

Comment: I see some of your older answers lack disclosure about you being an author to the package you are recommending, I am not flagging yet since you seem to have added those to your recent answers. Please edit your older answers where disclosure is missing.

Comment: @MNewville the first thing you did when you came here to Meta was to accuse the editors - who were in fact doing their jobs correctly - of abuse.  You didn't have to start that way, you could have said something like "I don't understand, is this editing correct... ", but no you went straight to "this is abuse".  Turns out that actually it was just your ignorance.  I haven't seen any retraction of your accusation yet, why is that?

Comment: [so], or the other sites in the community, aren't *forums* either, they are Q&A sites. Pages are a series of posts in response to each other, it's a *question* which can have 0 or more *answers*. There's no space for conversation in those posts. If you want a conversation then use [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=site&host=stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @JK. "I haven't seen any retraction of your accusation yet, why is that?" Either they still refuse to admit that they were wrong about that, or they've followed through on their threat to log out and never return. In my experience, probably both.

Answer (score 22):

> I have been answering questions about fairly specific technical topics and libraries - mostly ones for which I am a lead developer -- for several years.

Cool.

**Being a subject matter expert does not extend you special rights**. It does mean that people are likely to take your claims about the subject more seriously, as long as you *demonstrate* that subject matter expertise consistently, or else are at least well known (e.g. if any of those libraries are especially popular).

> Over the past few days, one person (who I do not know and who does not regularly discuss the topics or tools) has edited several of my answers.

This is normal operation of the site. As described [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), everyone who has accumulated at least 2,000 [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation) is granted the privilege of editing posts unilaterally, and **everyone may at least propose edits**. (Proposed edits are vetted *by the community, not just the author*.)

Stack Overflow is **not a blogging or other publishing platform**. If there is information you want to share with the world and you demand editorial control, use a site which provides that service. Then you are not even bound to the Q&A format, should you find it unsuitable.

The [purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of Stack Overflow is **fundamentally collaborative**. You do not get to dictate the style or tone of content you *contribute* to the site, any more than you would on Wikipedia.

When you post here, **[you grant](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) a license to your content** - to everyone in the entire world - that explicitly allows others to edit it. You [additionally grant certain rights to the company](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) not covered by the Creative Commons license.

> All the answers that have been edited in this way were asked and answered more than two years ago, and that answer was accepted more than two years ago. Several answers have a few upvotes. In many of these cases, my answer is the only answer to the question.

None of this helps your case in any way whatsoever. There is [no sense of urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569) on Stack Overflow and we fundamentally do not care about the age of content, **only about its suitability for the site** (notwithstanding historical locks on very few specific questions submitted under different standards for questions). We even [close questions as duplicates of newer ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938), if it means we can route people to better quality answers. if anything, as an answer ages, there is *more* reason to edit it, so as to keep it up to date.

> I would like the original answers reverted. For a few of these. I did restore the original answer but it was re-edited by a moderator. I have asked nicely to please revert the original answers in comments to the question, but it has not happened.

The request was not granted **because you have no basis for it.** It does not matter how nicely you ask. Your restoration was undone by the moderator because the edit was clearly in accordance with policy, whereas your rollback presumably reflected nothing more than a desire to have it your way.

Based on the comments on this question you may be interested in: [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/)

Additionally based on the comments: answers on the main site [are expected never to contain any kind of meta commentary, full stop]. If you need to explain that there is a problem with the question, **do not attempt to answer it**. The entire point of the site is to collect *usable, searchable* Q&As, and **not** to operate a help desk. Attempting to write answers to inappropriate questions actively makes the site worse: those questions pollute search results, and the answers [interfere with automatic cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions). For more information, please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) from the Help Center.

> Is there a place to report such abuse? I have a specific editor and moderator to report.

**If** there were any possibility of it being abusive, **this would be the right place** to begin the process of *investigating* possible abuse. In general you would be expected to have community consensus first in all but the most flagrant cases.

It is possible to go over our heads, for example by emailing the company. However, without a *compelling* case you will be *at best* perceived as wasting the time of someone who actually gets paid to care.

> I do not know if there is an official policy on editing accepted answers

There is quite a bit of related policy. **When you come to Meta, you are expected to have a basic awareness of the relevant policy** if you are going to file a grievance. If you are simply trying to find out what the policy is, you should not present yourself as if you know that policy or as if you know you are justified in feeling aggrieved. Being a subject matter expert in whatever technical topics does not make you any kind of subject matter expert in Stack Overflow policy, any more than it makes a subject matter expert in real-world law.

> Answering technical questions on SO is entirely my choice. I am under no obligation to participate in this forum at all. For the topic I focus on, there are very few people answering questions.

These things are true, and you are perfectly within your rights to leave. However, you are [expected not to make a scene about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290801/).

> Why would anyone expect a volunteer subject-matter expert to keep answering questions on this forum when it is tolerated that someone with no knowledge of the subject is allowed to edit accepted answers?

Because:

1. Many kinds of editing **do not require knowing** anything about the subject;
2. All the relevant policies are **applied fairly**, and you may equally well edit others' content to improve the site (so long as you understand the corresponding policy);
3. Such editing is a **free service provided by others in good faith** to improve your content, and make it more suitable for the site's Q&A format;
4. Q&A pages on Stack Overflow are **not private lines of communication** between the person asking and the person answering, but **publicly searchable
   documents** that have in some cases been accessed *literally millions of times*, and such edits can improve the experience for all of those people.

If you don't like the model, you are welcome not to participate. But [after 8 and a half years and hundreds of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5179748/m-newville), you have no real excuse for not at least understanding basic facts about the model. The relevant information is all over the place. Anyone who looks at the front page can see edits on a regular basis, for example, and it takes only 5 reputation to come here and ask more general questions (not motivated by self interest) before anything... more dramatic happens.

> If the original answers are not reverted, I will delete them.

Please do not do this. Part of the point of licensing your content to the site is that you have expressly permitted the community to share it. In extreme cases, moderators are empowered to suspend your account *and* undelete the content.

Aside from that, what you propose in your last paragraph is completely and utterly inconsistent with the title you gave to the post. (In cases of dispute over individual posts, moderators are empowered to block further edits to the post for some cooldown period.)

Comment: You might want to add that there is in fact a perfect place for things like "I support the other answer". Which is of course the comments section.  That we are not stopping that kind of conversational content, we are just making sure it goes to the right place.

Comment: @JK. actually that would still be comment abuse. Comments (on the main site) are for communicating problems with a question or answer, not to voice a personal opinion. It is more that it is condoned and thus the least bad place to do it because otherwise there would be no way for human beings to be human beings.